# How to use Selenium in Python to scrape contributors names from github page url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape contributors of a particular link (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/.gitignore) of github project bitcoin. I am using Selenium. I am scraping contributors where it is written “44 contributors”. My code scrape the contributors name only when I manually go to the page and click on “44contributors ”. Otherwise, it results in empty list of contributors. Please help me to make my code work even without going to the page and clicking “44 contributors”. Below is the snapshot of the pages before and after clicking:

[image]

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\saran\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/.gitignore')
contributors=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.Box-body.d-flex.flex-items-center.flex-auto.f6.border-bottom-0.flex-wrap >\
                                            details#blob_contributors_box >\
                                            details-dialog >\
                                            ul >li.Box-row > a.link-gray-dark.no-underline')
contri_names=[]
for n in contributors:
  contri_names.append(n.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

Comment: Look into the github API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have extracted the names from the profile links of the contributors

```
#importing libraries
import requests
import os
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#opening a chrome instance
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe")

#getting to the link
driver.get('https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/.gitignore')

#opening the names of the contributors
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="blob_contributors_box"]').click()

#getting the elements
names=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="blob_contributors_box"]/details-dialog/ul/li/a')

#getting the links of the contibutors page
ids=[]
for name in names:
    ids +=[name.get_attribute('href')
           for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="blob_contributors_box"]/details-dialog/ul/li[1]/a')]

#getting the name from the links
ppl_names=[]
for id in ids:
    ppl_name=id.replace('https://github.com/','')
    ppl_names.append(ppl_name)

#print names
ppl_names
```